# Is this matrix guaranteed to be positive-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

(This question pertains to a larger model proposed in [this SIGRAPH paper](http://graphics.berkeley.edu/papers/Liu-FSM-2013-11/Liu-FSM-2013-11.pdf), but I've pulled out the pertinent question and generalized it.)

Let's say I have two large matrices $M$ and $L \in\mathbb{R}^{3n \times 3n}$, where $M$ is some blocked diagonal [mass matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_matrix) such that $M = diag[m_1I_3, m_2I_3,...,m_nI_3]$ where $m_i>0$, and $L$ is the Kronecker product of some Laplacian matrix $L_q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $I_3$ ($L = L_q \otimes I_3)$.

I'm trying to compute the Cholesky factorization of $M + aL$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}, a > 0$. The paper that I found this problem in claims that since $L$ is symmetric positive semi-definite and $M$ is symmetric positive-definite, $M + aL$ is guaranteed to be positive-definite, but when I attempt to compute the Cholesky of the matrix the LA library I'm using (Math.Net Numerics) says the matrix isn't positive-definite.

The matrix in question is too large to check practically by hand (700x700-ish) and I'm a little iffy on the theory here. Is the paper incorrect about $M + aL$ being positive-definite, or have I made a mistake in my code?

Comment: You might have a mistake in your code. You can check (in your code) that both $M$ and $L$ are really symmetric. Positive definiteness can be checked, e.g., by computing their eigenvalues (in MATLAB, Octave, using a routine in LAPACK, etc.) or the $LDL^T$ factorisation (all pivots must be positive or non-negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is positive-definite: if $x \not= 0$  then
$$x^T (M+aL) x = x^T M x + a x^TLx > 0,$$
since $x^TMx > 0$ and $x^TLx \geq 0$.

Comment: In retrospect I probably should have realized that this was solvable with a distribution. Thanks.